# MathJax slow and often times out

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Recently MathJax (e.g. using MathML or other renderers - doesn't matter) on SE sites seems to be stuck all the time waiting for cdn.sstatic.net or cloudflare and often simply times out. Usually reloading the page fixes it. My question first of all is why on each and every page MathJax has to call those servers: could I not pre-install a whole MathJax on my system, for example? Isn't there a local cache? What other things could I try to speedup MathJax rendering on SE pages?

Comment: for me the mathjax.js loads in 96ms. Can you elaborate which browser you are using, where you are located in the world, which ISP you use, if it changes if you use a different ISP. Is it on all pages or only a few? Can you show the  network tab of the developer console of your browser with those load times?

Comment: The MathJax.js file has for me an expire header set in Dec, 12th, 2018 so I would expect that file to be served from cache for almost a year.

Comment: You might want to try clearing your cache in case parts of MathJax were corrupted during download.

Comment: what browser? there's usually some favour of performance monitoring which might be helpful in fingering your proble